# Radio button validation in react js. Cannot get my error message when nothing is selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i add validation to my radio buttons here.
I want to show the message when the user selects neither of the radio buttons and submits the form. It's working but I get my error message even when one radio button is selected. Anything I'm missing in my logic ?

```
 <div className='formfields'>
                        <label htmlFor='gender'
                        className='gender' >
                        Gender
                        </label>
                        <input type='radio'
                         id='male'
                        name='male'
                         value='male'                     
                         onChange={inputChanger}/>
                         <label htmlFor='male'>Male</label>
                         <input type='radio'
                         id='female'
                        name='female'
                         value='female'
                         onChange={inputChanger}/>
                         <label htmlFor="female">Female</label><br></br>
                         {errors.gender && <p>{errors.gender}</p>}
                    </div>
    
     if(!(datas.gender == 'male' || datas.gender =='female') )
        {
            errors.gender = 'Select a gender'
        }
```

Comment: Would you post your HTML code?

Comment: you mean the whole code ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to convert the following statement:

```
if(!(datas.gender == 'male' || datas.gender =='female') )
```

to

```
if((datas.gender===undefined)|| !(datas.gender == 'male' || datas.gender =='female'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a state and change it in the buttons:

```
onClick={()=>{this.setState(gender:'male')}
```